# Парсер jsonb через json_to_recordset

Tags: postgresql, парсер, jsonb

Не могу понять, чего не хватает, чтобы вытащить массив с колонками name и index
из JSON.

```
select * from json_to_recordset(select '{"title": "Статистика по кассирам",
"filters": [{"name": "Дата с", "value": "01.01.1999", "property": "datebeg"},
{"name": "Дата по", "value": "01.12.2999", "property": "dateend"}], 
"selection": [{"name": "ФИО", "index": 0, "orderby": 0, "property": "user_name", "isvisible": true},
{"name": "Отдел", "index": 1, "orderby": 0, "property": "ware_name", "isvisible": true}]}':: jsonb -> 'selection') 
as x(name text, index int) order by index
```

Спасибо

Comment: Дополните вопрос.  Непонятно, что у вас не работает.  И ещё, пишите правки в вопрос, а не в комментарий.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вроде бы это ответ, а не правка вопроса?

Comment: @Ainar-G, а почему ты считаешь, что это правка, а не ответ?

Comment: @mcmot, если проблема решена, то решение стоит постить в ответе, а не в комментарии. Или это действительно дополнение вопроса? Тогда надо править вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хм... Вроде как я решил, что это дополнение к вопросу. Типа "вот такое у меня решение есть, но оно мне не совсем нравится". Возможно, действительно имелся в виду ответ, а не уточнение о возможном но не идеальном решении)

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом, просто изначально хотел сделать не используя шаблоны для jsonb_populate_recordset

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE index_table(property text, index int); json_column_index := ARRAY ( SELECT property FROM (select * from jsonb_populate_recordset( NULL :: index_table, ( SELECT '{"title": "Статистика", "filters": [{"name": "Дата с", "value": "01.01.1999", "property": "datebeg"}], "selection": [{"name": "ФИО", "index": 0, "property": "user_name"}, {"name": "Отдел", "index": 1, "property": "ware_name"}]}':: jsonb -> 'selection')) as CIS order by index) AS column_index_out);
```